# how to update a string upon variable change in Swift

Tags: swift

sorry for the VERY beginner question... I am just learning to code Swift. 
I am defining a variable, then printing a conditioned message based on its value. When I change the variable to another value I would expect the message string to change, but it doesn't. What am I doing wrong?
This is the code:

```
//: Playground - noun: a place where people can play

import Cocoa

var str = "Hello, playground"


var townname = "Azadinos"
var population: Int = 5422
var message: String
var Haspostoffice: Bool = true

if population < 10000 {
        message = "with a population of \(population), \(townname) is a small town"
} else if population >= 10000 && population < 15000 {
        message = "with a population of \(population), \(townname) is a medium sized town!"
}else {message = "\(townname) is a huge town!"}

print (message)

population = 250000

print (population)

print(message)
```

I would expect that the second message is different than the first one, but it isn't. What am I doing wrong?
thanks a lot

Comment: Simple answer: you set the variable `message`, then didn't update it based on the new `population` value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should go through the `String Interpolation` in Swift [Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/StringsAndCharacters.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH7-ID285)

`String interpolation` helps you to put a new `string` value from a mixed combination of `constants, variables, literals, and expressions` by including their values inside a `string literal`. For example as in above doc:

```
let multiplier = 3 //This is constant
let message = "\(multiplier) times 2.5 is \(Double(multiplier) * 2.5)"
// message prints :   "3 times 2.5 is 7.5"
```

Here is your working code:

```
var townname = "Azadinos"
var population: Int = 5422
var message: String
var Haspostoffice: Bool = true

if population < 10000 {
   message = "with a population of \(population), \(townname) is a small town"
} else if population >= 10000 && population < 15000 {
   message = "with a population of \(population), \(townname) is a medium sized town!"
} else {
   message = "\(townname) is a huge town!"
}

print (message)
population = 250000
print (population)
print(message)
```

Now as your question `why it is not updating for second message`, you should write a function and then do the changes to your variable. Because your code runs in single flow i.e starts and ends on your last line. Your `if-else` conditions doesn't know that if there is a change in the `variable(message)`. So if you want that to happen, either you have to write your `if-else` conditions once again after you modify the `message` variable or just create `function` and call the function once `message` gets changed. Just look at below code if makes sense. Try to write your function in different way.

```
var townname = "Azadinos"
var population: Int = 5422
var message = ""
var Haspostoffice: Bool = true

func printMyVars() {
    if population < 10000 {
        message = "with a population of \(population), \(townname) is a small town"
    } else if population >= 10000 && population < 15000 {
        message = "with a population of \(population), \(townname) is a medium sized town!"
    } else {
        message = "\(townname) is a huge town!"
    }
    print(message)
}
printMyVars()
population = 250000
printMyVars()
```

This prints:

```
with a population of 5422, Azadinos is a small town
Azadinos is a huge town!
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help! Its much appreciated, and a good lesson.

Comment: Please mark it as answer if it helped you to fix your issue.

Answer (score 0):

you must execute if statement after change population.

```
//: Playground - noun: a place where people can play

import Cocoa

var str = "Hello, playground"

var townname = "Azadinos" 
var population: Int = 5422 
var message:     String 
var Haspostoffice: Bool = true

if population < 10000 {
    message = "with a population of \(population), \(townname) is a small town"
} else if population >= 10000 && population < 15000 {
    message = "with a population of \(population), \(townname) is a medium sized town!"
} else {
    message = "\(townname) is a huge town!"
}
print (message)
population = 250000
print (population)
// Do If statement after changing population
if population < 10000 {
    message = "with a population of \(population), \(townname) is a small town"
} else if population >= 10000 && population < 15000 {
    message = "with a population of \(population), \(townname) is a medium sized town!"
} else {
    message = "\(townname) is a huge town!"
}
print(message)
```

I recommend making function to simplify code. Like the following code(I didn't run this code).

```
//: Playground - noun: a place where people can play

import Cocoa

var str = "Hello, playground"

var townname = "Azadinos" 
var population: Int = 5422 
var message:     String 
var Haspostoffice: Bool = true

func makeMessage(population: Int) -> String {
    if population < 10000 {
        message = "with a population of \(population), \(townname) is a small town"
    } else if population >= 10000 && population < 15000 {
        message = "with a population of \(population), \(townname) is a medium sized town!"
    } else {
        message = "\(townname) is a huge town!"
    }
    return message
}

message = makeMessage(population)
print (message)
population = 250000
print (population)
message = makeMessage(population)
print(message)
```